# conditional expression behaviour for assignment statement in c

Tags: c

In the first program below there is no error.But for the second program there is an error.
Why is that so?

First program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int k=8;
int m=7;
k<m?k=k+1:m+1;
printf("%d",k);
}
```

Second program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int k=8;
int m=7;
k<m?k=k+1:m=m+1;
printf("%d",k);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any error..Post the error please?

Comment: lvalue required as left operand of assignment is the error given

Comment: I think you have uncovered an error in gcc's implementation. File a bug, and add parentheses around both sides of your conditional to work around the issue.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think he doesn't uncovered any bug in `gcc`, see my answer.

Comment: @ouah You're right, the reason it worked on "some compilers" was that these were compilers from a different language (I mean C++ of course :) Very good find!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditional operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator. You need extra parentheses to have the desired precedence.

```
k < m? k = k + 1 : m = m + 1;
```

is evaluated as

```
((k < m) ? (k = k + 1) : m) = m + 1;
```

Add parentheses to have the correct precedence:

```
(k < m) ? (k = k + 1) : (m = m + 1);
```

Comment: I don't know any C compiler that accepts it. Are you sure you are not compiling with `g++`?

Comment: @PaulR the result of the assignment operator is not a lvalue in C but is a lvalue in C++, that's why you don't get the error in C++. But even in C++ it still has not the desired precedence.

Comment: Aha - that explains it - I guess ideone.com is compiling this as C++.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an error in it.Both program gives an output of 8 which is correct.